# Cannot install mysql server locally

Tags: server, mysql

I user ubuntu 14.04 version.

So I can't install mysql-server.

```
    Unpacking mysql-server-core-5.6 (5.6.27-0ubuntu0.14.04.1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.6.7.1-1ubuntu1) ...
Setting up mysql-common (5.6.25-3+deb.sury.org~trusty+1) ...
update-alternatives: using /etc/mysql/my.cnf.fallback to provide /etc/mysql/my.cnf (my.cnf) in auto mode
Selecting previously unselected package mysql-server-5.6.
(Reading database ... 219897 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../mysql-server-5.6_5.6.27-0ubuntu0.14.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mysql-server-5.6 (5.6.27-0ubuntu0.14.04.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package mysql-server.
Preparing to unpack .../mysql-server_5.6.25-3+deb.sury.org~trusty+1_all.deb ...
Unpacking mysql-server (5.6.25-3+deb.sury.org~trusty+1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.6.7.1-1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-16) ...
Setting up libmysqlclient18:amd64 (5.6.25-3+deb.sury.org~trusty+1) ...
Setting up libdbd-mysql-perl (4.025-1) ...
Setting up mysql-client-core-5.6 (5.6.27-0ubuntu0.14.04.1) ...
Setting up mysql-client-5.6 (5.6.27-0ubuntu0.14.04.1) ...
Setting up mysql-server-core-5.6 (5.6.27-0ubuntu0.14.04.1) ...
Setting up mysql-server-5.6 (5.6.27-0ubuntu0.14.04.1) ...
start: Job failed to start
invoke-rc.d: initscript mysql, action "start" failed.
dpkg: error processing package mysql-server-5.6 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mysql-server:
 mysql-server depends on mysql-server-5.6; however:
  Package mysql-server-5.6 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package mysql-server (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.19-0ubuntu6.6) ...
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                          Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-16) ...
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
A package failed to install.  Trying to recover:
Setting up mysql-server-5.6 (5.6.27-0ubuntu0.14.04.1) ...
start: Job failed to start
invoke-rc.d: initscript mysql, action "start" failed.
dpkg: error processing package mysql-server-5.6 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mysql-server:
 mysql-server depends on mysql-server-5.6; however:
  Package mysql-server-5.6 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package mysql-server (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-server-5.6
 mysql-server
```

I tried to purge all packages installed, related to mysql. 
And this:

```
apt-get purge mysql-server
apt-get purge mysql-common
rm -rf /var/log/mysql
rm -rf /var/log/mysql.*
rm -rf /var/lib/mysql
rm -rf /etc/mysql
# and then:
apt-get install mysql-server --fix-missing --fix-broken
```

But even after it I cannot install mysql.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

First remove MySQL:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge mysql-server mysql-client mysql-common -y
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get autoclean
```

Then install MySQL again:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install mysql-server -y
```

Comment: still the same issue

Comment: @eatmypants Try `sudo apt-get upgrade` and then `sudo apt-get -f install mysql-server`

Comment: stille the same

Comment: @eatmypants Try `sudo apt-get --reinstall install mysql-server-5.5`

Comment: cannot install it even with synaptic. Tell's me that it's broken;

Comment: @eatmypants One last time according to your error above it is not installing `mysql-server-5.6` so try `sudo apt-get install -f mysql-server-5.6`

Comment: unfortunately, still the same

Comment: You could try `sudo dpkg-reconfigure --force mysql-server-5.6`

Comment: @TungTran, still the same thing

Comment: @eatmypants have you tried to use the synaptic package manager to fix the mysql-server package?

Comment: @eatmypants Here is the link to that https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SynapticHowto it is at the very bottom.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose it's due to [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mysql-5.6/+bug/1312936). May your machine have low memory. Get to `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` and decrease `max_connection` to lower value. And then restart your installation:

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

Comment: there is no values such as max_connection. When I try to set max_connection = 100, i got the same issue.

Comment: There should be max_connection but it may be commented out. By default, the its value is 100. You should decrease it by a lower value. Btw, how much RAM do you have?

Comment: 12gb. Quite enough for this :)

Comment: ok, try to increase `key_buffer=512M`

Comment: still the same error here